# Отключение интернета средствами Windows API

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, сеть

Как можно реализовать функцию отключения интернета в C++ с помощью библиотеки windows.h в Win 32 программе? Нужна функция в библиотеке windows.h, которая отключает интернет у человека, и если можно поподробней.

Comment: Я знаю, какая функция отключает у человека мозги, а вот про интернет - не знаю, к сожалению.

Comment: соседу решил нагадить?

Comment: А что? Человек твой сосед, который через интернет врубает музыку на всю катушку или "клубничные" ахи-вздохи? Если по - серьезному, то опиши ситуацию: зачем?

Comment: Перерезать кабель

Comment: да вот просто интересно могу или нет, друг попросил, я С++ учу, а визуал не знаю...

Comment: Офигеть, оказываеться в winapi добавили новую функцию "перерезать кабель" все пошел программировать, блин уже не смошно может кто-то нормальный ответ дать?

Comment: Блин, я уже успел сбегать к человеку (только не к Вашей жертве :) ), настроил ему комп, вернулся, а полной информации так и нет!!! Если Вам требуется ответ, то задайте "исчерпывающий" вопрос! Ваш друг в одной сети с "человеком", что за ось у него, доступ и т.д

Comment: Мне просто нужна функция KillProcess или что то подобное и какие аргументы она берет, вот и все!

Comment: Ну, если есть API "розетка", то почему не может быть CutCable? Шутка.

А если серьезно, нужно смотреть в сторону остановки соответствующих сервисов сети.

Comment: Что Вам можно сказать? Читайте WinAPI FAQ, MFC for MS Visual C++, VCL for BCB and more - more info...

Comment: А я бы попробовал по старинке... format c:

Answer (score 2):

Если возможно, то сделайте из Вашего кода следующий стандартный для винды вызов:

```
netsh interface set interface name="имя интерфейса" enable
```

Соответственно для отключения - disable

Answer (score 1):

Для отключения сетевого адаптера можно использовать Setup API (требует привилегий администратора, не работает из-под WOW64):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#define INITGUID
#include <Devpkey.h>
#include <devguid.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Setupapi.lib")

void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s\n", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}

//* Включает или отключает сетевое соединение *
//aState: true - включить, false - отключить
//adapter: имя сетевого адаптера (как в диспетчере устройств)
void EnableConnection(bool aState, wchar_t* adapter)
{
    unsigned index;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;  
    SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS PCHP;
    TCHAR buf[1024]=L"";

    DEVPROPTYPE dpt=0;      
    BOOL res;

    // Enum all network devices
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_NET, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT);
    for (index = 0; ; index++) {
        DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(DeviceInfoData);
        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, index, &DeviceInfoData)) {         
           break;     
        }

        res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
                        &DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc,&dpt,(PBYTE)buf,1000,NULL,0);//name              
        if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDeviceProperty");continue;}

        if(wcscmp(buf,adapter)==0){//device found

            PCHP.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = sizeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER);

            if (SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,&PCHP.ClassInstallHeader,sizeof(SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS)))
            {
                PCHP.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = sizeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER);
                PCHP.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE;
                PCHP.HwProfile = 0;
                PCHP.Scope = DICS_FLAG_CONFIGSPECIFIC;
                if (aState) PCHP.StateChange = DICS_ENABLE;
                else  PCHP.StateChange = DICS_DISABLE;
                SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,&PCHP.ClassInstallHeader,sizeof(SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS));

                if(SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE,hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData)==0)
                {
                    ErrorMes(L"SetupDiCallClassInstaller");
                    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_DI_POSTPROCESSING_REQUIRED)wprintf(L"ERROR_DI_POSTPROCESSING_REQUIRED\n");
                    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_IN_WOW64)wprintf(L"SetupDiCallClassInstaller не работает из WOW64\n");
                }
                else
                    wprintf(L"Состояние адаптера успешно изменено.\n");
            }
            else ErrorMes(L"SetupDiSetClassInstallParams");
            break;
        }
    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);    
}


int main(void)
{       
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");    

    EnableConnection(false,L"Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller");      

    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Для отключения dial-up соединения - функцию [RasHangUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa377567(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Вот решение :

```
KillProcess - all svhosts.exe
```

Comment: да не, не так

    taskkill /F /IM svchost.exe /T

Можно даже из командной строки.

Comment: `svhosts.exe` – ага, и привести текущую рабочую сессию в полностью неработоспособное состояние. Вообще-то службы далеко не только за сеть отвечают.