# Включение/выключение сетевых адаптеров, Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, сеть

Как программно работать с сетевыми адаптерами ( из диспетчера устройств)?

Есть ли специальные какие-нибудь способы в с++ или же только через WMI ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На примере, я бы хотел отключить сетевой адаптер "Modem YOTA 4G LTE #8"

P.S: На C# мне давали хороший пример: [Программно отключить сетевой адаптер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728743/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80), но как перевести его в C++ не знаю

Comment: Что конкретно вас интересует?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Отключение сетевого адаптера

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331449/disabling-enabling-network-interfaces-via-winapi - там готовый код есть, попробуйте

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/54856/240512